# Displaying values using for loop: 60, 58, 56, 54, 52

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to display values in this way: 60, 58, 56, 54, 52...... But struggling to come up with a logic to keep it consistent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `60 - 2n` for `n = 0` to `n = 30` :v

Comment: Are you able to recognize the relationship that there is between these numbers?

Comment: Come on guys stop marking as a bad question and help me. Thats not fair with someone who is new in this field.

Comment: Finally got the solution. Thanks @MohammadAliBaydoun

  int b = 60;
  for (int i=0; i < 30  ; i++ )
  {
   System.out.println(b-2*i);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
    int b = 60;
    for (int i=0; i < 30  ; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println(b-2*i);
    }
```

Comment: I you can't accept other's answers',kindly accept your answer at least!

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the upper limit");
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int n = in.nextInt();
if(n%2==0) {
    for (int i=n;i>0;i-=2){
        list.add(i);
    }
}
else{
    for (int i=n-1;i>0;i-=2){
        list.add(i);
    }
}
for(Integer i :list){
    System.out.print(i+"  ");
}
```

First you can ask user to enter the limit from which you want to display the even series then check if the limit is even if it is just perform the logic it is odd then display the series from the next lower even of the limit